# How to show the name by using date field

Tags: visualforce

I have a date field in salesforce when i enter any value in date field i have to show the name field how can i achive it.Can anyone help on it

```
<apex:inputField value="{!ee.Date__c}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!ee.name}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <apex:outputpanel id="panel1">
     <apex:inputfield value="{ee.name}" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(ee.Date__c))}"/>
   </apex:outputpanel>  

  <apex:outputpanel id="panel 2">
     <apex:inputfield value="{!ee.Date}"  >
       <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="panel1" />
     </apex:inputfield>
   </apex:outputpanel>
```

note: your action support might have to call an apex action to set the value of ee.Date__c during the onchange event..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript tricks as shown below:

```
 <apex:form>
  <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}" onkeyup="document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0].style.display='block'" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}" styleClass="className" style="display:none;"/>
    </apex:form>
```